# SMTP connect() failed error in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am completely new to PHP and I want to send a mail using PHP. I have a Contact Us form whcih will accept email is of the person contacting me and therefore the mail will be sent to me. I am using PHPMailer library from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master and following is the code snippet I am using.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Host     = "resolver1.opendns.com"; // this SMTP server of my machine
//$mail->Host     = "208.67.222.222";//ip ; which one to use the resolver1.opendns.com or 208.67.222.222 ???

$mail->From     = "xyz@gamil.com;//email id of the person 

$mail->AddAddress("datta.dhonde@coreathena.com");//my email id

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}  
else 
{
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

I am getting the error " Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed."
I am not getting what is the problem..?
$mail->Host = "";        please comment on what this stands for??

Comment: If there is an IPv6 address in your network interface then please remove it.

Comment: I don't think that resolver1.opendns.com is going to accept your email.

Comment: I had to add `$mail->Port = $SmtpPort;` for it to work. It worked on the development server but not on the production one before that.

Answer (score 24):

Add `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` and try to debug the problem.

Comment: For me, on my RHEL system I got this error when I had configured Postfix but hadn't switched it to the default MTA using alternatives yet.

Answer (score 4):

As very well exampled by @joydesigner, To connect via SMTP, you will need to pass `hostname, username and password` and then it should connect and send email.

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // tls or ssl connection as req
```

Here I see you have passed only, `host` information, pls add `username & password` as well and try once.

Also check that `TLS/SSL PORT` is open for your server:

check with:

```
telnet resolver1.opendns.com 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is your configuration problem.

example of phpmailer configuration is like this:

```
<?php
 require 'class.phpmailer.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;

 $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
 $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

 $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
 $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
 $mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
 $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
 $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
 $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
 $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

 $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
 $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
 $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

 $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
 $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

 if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
 }

 echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Here the $mail->Host is the smtp mail server. Normally started with smtp.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the tcp port 25 of the resolver1.opendns.com , it seens being block or not starting up the stmpd such as sendmail or some MTA.

try
telnet resolver1.opendns.com 25

and you will find tcp port 25 is not opened.