# Phpmailer works on localhost, but not on server

Tags: smtp, server, localhost, phpmailer

I use the same script on localhost (wamp server) and on 1und1 server. **With the same SMTP settings**.

**On localhost I can send emails**, but on the server I can't. The error that I get on host is: SMTP connect() failed.

I was asking to 1und1 support and they told me to check my script...

Can someone tell me if they are wrong or is a problem with my script ?

```
if(isset($_GET['send_mail']))
{
    require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.1und1.de';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '***********';
    $mail->Password = '***********';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
    $mail->Port = '587';

    $mail->From = 'newsletter@website.de';
    $mail->FromName = 'newsletter@website.de';
    $mail->AddAddress('my.email@zoho.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('newsletter@website.de');
    $mail->Subject = 'This is a title';
    $mail->Body    = 'Body content';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Body content again';

    if($mail->send())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connect() failed error in PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288162/smtp-connect-failed-error-in-phpmailer)

Comment: Search before you post, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki). There are hundreds of duplicates of this question.

Comment: I already check other questions from stack and nothing solve my problem. It's not a duplicate from my opinion. It's a particularly problem. Synchro, read my post, including the market bold text.

Comment: Ok, so post the results you got from all the tests suggested on the troubleshooting page (as you have obviously already done all those), and your debug output, since you already have that enabled.

Comment: This is the error from debug (2): 2015-11-08 20:47:22 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2015-11-08 20:47:22 SMTP connect() failed. SMTP connect() failed. Also try it with smtp details from gmail. On localhost it works and on server it doesn't....

Comment: Right, so like the docs say, you have a connectivity problem on your server. Figure out what that is using the guide, fix it, and phpmailer will be able to work.

Comment: Are you kidding ? I already say that I CAN SEND FROM LOCALHOST, but not from the server ! What can i figure here ? If you can figure something, tell me. Else, please stop posting.

Comment: I don't know how I can make this any clearer. Your local machine does not have a connection problem. Your server does. I've told you how to diagnose the problem, it's up to you to actually do it. This is **nothing** to do with PHPMailer, and your offensive attitude is not going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your web space/server at 1und1 already connected with your mail server. You have only to use `mail(...)`, nothing more.

```
<?php
   $to = "sendto@domain.de";
   $subject = "Mail-fenter code hereunction";
   $from = "From: Nils  <from@domain.de>";
   $text = "your html or something";

   mail($to, $subject, $text, $from);
?>
```