# could not sending mail from Gmail using PhpMailer in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail from Gmail account Using PhpMailer in codeigniter But it says an error :

**Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

What i am doing in code :

```
$this->load->library('MY_PHPMailer');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'xamplee@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '123456';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'test';
        $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'MT');
        $mail->addReplyTo('example@gmail.com', 'MT');
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'test using';
        $mail->Body = 'Hi 2';
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        }
        echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: Do you think you might possibly find out how to fix this if you follow that link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connect() failed error in PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288162/smtp-connect-failed-error-in-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have not allowed access in gmail.
You need to allow access for less secure apps in gmail in order to send emails using that account. You can refer this link to do so:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

You need to add this line too:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```